# Any algorithm/logic to generate 6 digit alphanumeric unique identifier in a multi process setup

Tags: java, concurrency, uniqueidentifier

I have a use case where I need to generate 6 digit alphanumeric unique identifier. Have come across many solution but all seems to be fail in a multi processor environment and also might generate same unique identifier at some point of time.

Is there any solution/algorithm to generate 6 digit alphanumeric unique identifiers at run time in a multi processor environment and should generate unique identifier always.

Comment: Which range of characters constitutes an alphanumeric "digit"?

Comment: One way is to generate (random) while the id exist, so you need to store in a file/database/... all ids, but if you want unique id across several machines, it will not work (except if you share your file/database/...)

Comment: when you say multi processor, do you mean multiple machines or just one with different threads?

Answer (score 1):

Six alphanumeric characters is way too few for a guaranteed globally unique I'd.
If that's your requirement, your best bet is, probably, to keep a counter in a global variable, return  base64 - encoded value as the next I'd when needed, and increase the counter atomically.

If you need this to work across different machines, out the counter into a database (sequence). You can assigned ranges to each server, to avoid making a db query every time a new I'd is generated.

Comment: Thanks Dima, would it be possible for you to put some psuedo code here about the approach you were talking...

Comment: @storia321 Sure, here:  `String getId()  { return Base64.encode(counter++); }`

Answer (score 1):

A simple sequence of numbers starting at `0` and increasing by `1` would generate a non-repeating sequence (obviously stopping at the end or when you exceed 6 digits). Generate the number in base `36` and it is alpha-numeric.

To make that accessable concurrently you merely need to put the sequence generator in a `Runnable` and run it in a thread that feeds a `BlockingQueue`. You can then pull numbers off the queue in a thread-safe fashion. Something like this:

```
class SafeSequence implements Runnable {

    // My current value.
    long i = 0;
    // Use BlockingQueue to assist cuncurrency.
    BlockingQueue<Long> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

    String get() throws InterruptedException {
        // Format at take time.
        return Long.toString(q.take(), 36);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // Always runs in it's own thread so no concurrency issues.
                q.put(i++);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // Just drops out of the loop on iterruption.
        }
    }

}
```

If you don't want sequential you could use an [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) to generate the sequence.

Comment: I need the unique ID 6 digit in length always and should contains alphanumeric always

Comment: @storia321 - Base 36 will always be alphanumeric. Add leading zeros to achieve 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [commons-id](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/index.html) ? You may be interested in some variant of **UUID version 1**, The standard UUIDs provided are 128 bit long though.

Comment: With this, written following code to generate unique which is working perfectly. Curious to know whether these APIs widely used in the industry. Any idea.    AlphanumericGenerator obj = new AlphanumericGenerator(false, 6);
  Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
  
  for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
      set.add(obj.nextStringIdentifier());
  }

Comment: Can't answer your industry question. Regarding the code - you don't need it to run on multiple VMs or invoke it from multiple threads?